# Mean for a time period

Tags: r, mean

This is a bit of a tricky one. I have a dataset with data for a variable for N individuals for T years, and I have a dummy (new_regime) which takes value 1 if a new regime has started and is 0 otherwise.

```
individual|year|new_regime|variable
------------------------------------
   1        1       1         0.5
   1        2       0         0.78
   1        3       0         0.9
   1        4       0         0.76
   1        5       1         0.86
```

What I want is to be able to compute the mean for variable until the next realization of a new regime. Essentially I want to create something like:

```
individual|year|new_regime|variable|mean_variable|
--------------------------------------------------
   1        1       1         0.5        0.735
   1        2       0         0.78       0.735
   1        3       0         0.9        0.735
   1        4       0         0.76       0.735
   1        5       1         0.86
```

Also I should add some of the values for variable are NA such that:

```
individual|year|new_regime|variable|
------------------------------------
   2        1       1         0.5        
   2        2       0         NA       
   2        3       0         0.9        
   2        4       0         0.76       
   2        5       1         0.86
```

But in this case I would still like to figure out the mean of the existing observations such that:

```
individual|year|new_regime|variable|mean_variable|
-------------------------------------------------
   2        1       1         0.5        0.72     
   2        2       0         NA         0.72  
   2        3       0         0.9        0.72     
   2        4       0         0.76       0.72
```

I don't even know where to begin with this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(individual) %>%
  mutate(regime_idx = cumsum(new_regime)) %>%
  group_by(individual, regime_idx) %>% # or group_by(regime_idx, .add = TRUE)
  mutate(mean_variable = case_when(regime_idx == 1L ~ mean(variable, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% # or just mutate(mean_variable = mean(variable, na.rm = TRUE)) if you want output for all regimes
  ungroup %>%
  select(-regime_idx)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   individual  year new_regime variable mean_variable
        <int> <int>      <int>    <dbl>         <dbl>
 1          1     1          1     0.5          0.735
 2          1     2          0     0.78         0.735
 3          1     3          0     0.9          0.735
 4          1     4          0     0.76         0.735
 5          1     5          1     0.86        NA    
 6          2     1          1     0.5          0.72 
 7          2     2          0    NA            0.72 
 8          2     3          0     0.9          0.72 
 9          2     4          0     0.76         0.72 
10          2     5          1     0.86        NA
```